# Game store deployment on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shopify, e-commerce

I am working on a store in WordPress. I want to sell digital keycodes for games and also the game accessories, but I don't have money first to buy them and then sell on the store. So I wanted to ask if there is any way that customers place an order on my website and the order is completed through another website for him.
Like if the customer buys a game controller from my store, the order will be fulfilled my website like amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the order will have to be completed on another website but that website will need to have an affiliate program. For example Amazon has affiliate programs and to get sale revenue you just need to add an affiliate link to the product.

That is done very easily with WooCommerce plugin for WordPress.
Each product can be set to redirect to an external link, an affiliate link.
To do that inside of WooCommerce:
Simply choose External/Affiliate product from the Product Data dropdown menu when editing your product.

Add the product URL. This will be the affiliate link or other links you were given that lead the customer directly to the outside site.

You can do the same without WooCommerce but it is a lot simpler to handle pricing, stock/inventory, variations for products using WooCommerce.

Comment: but this will redirect my customer to Amazon. I don't want my customer to redirect to that site that's why I asked this question.

Comment: I only mentioned Amazon to give you an example. The link can go to any website, it doesn't have to be to Amazon. As long as that website has an affiliate program **just like Amazon**.